# Статус пользователя

Tags: mysqli, php

Подскажите как сделать именно на куках, если куки есть то есть если пользователь в аккаунте то мы обновляем запись в бд, нашего пользователя на status=1, если же не существует куков логина и пароля то мы обновляем запись на status=0. Ну или подскажите свой простой вариант только что бы не по ип... Спасибо.

Comment: держи, пригодится: ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Я первое предложение вообще не понял. Пишите грамотно

Comment: *Покапитаню. Как сделать уже сказали, а почему нельзя просто выставить status=0?  
Потому что, если пользователь не залогинен, то кому ставить этот ноль?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потелепатирую немного. ТС просит подсказать как реализовать функцию просмотра в списке пользователей кто онлайн. Как правило такие вещи делаются в два потока. Первый - при каждом переходе пользователем по сайту обновляется строка в БД (к примеру ячейка status таблицы users, куда записывается дата-время этого действия). Второй этап - при выводе списка пользователей (или единичного пользователя) отправляется запрос к ячейке status и создаётся переменная текущего дата-время. Также из конфига берётся переменная указывающая сколько времени считать пользователя онлайн (к примеру 5 минут). Отнимая от текущего времени время записанное в бд, у всех пользователей, у которых полученный результат меньше 5 минут, выставлять значок "онлайн". Привязываться к кукисы смысла нету. Изменять поле status только у зарегистрированных-залогиненных пользователей.